# How to set expiry to .js file, .css file and images only using meta tags or php code not in .htaccess

Tags: html, http-headers, meta-tags

[Without using .htaccess file, setting expiry only using metatags or php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ISdM.png)

Comment: any one please answer it...

Answer (score 0):

You could load each resources with a different timestamp each time your page is shown :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?time=<?php echo mktime(); ?>" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/myfile.css?time=<?php echo mktime(); ?>">`

**Note: This is not good idea to load using PHP in terms of security.  You should use .htaccess**